# expresión regular python buscar etiqueta capturar datos

Tags: python, regex

Estoy intentando generar una regex que me devuelva los datos asociados a unas etiquetas determinadas, y repetidas varias veces en un String. Que me devuelva los datos entre ><.
ejemplo:  `"<measResults>1 2 3 4 </measResults>"` pero no lo hago bien. `re.findall(r"<measResults>([0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+)+",string)`. Ya que, o me deja etiquetas sin detectar, o datos sin capturar.
Gracias adelantadas.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Remitente>
               <Nombre>Nombre del remitente</Nombre>
               <Mail> Correo del remitente </Mail>
```

Tengo que atrapar en los diferentes niveles del árbol, tanto lo que esta entre >< como las cadenas después del igual. 
Ya lo he realizado a mi manera, pero me hubiera gustado haber conseguido un regex que hiciera todo el trabajo, al pasar todo el documento a String.

Comment: Hola Fernando, ¿el dato es siempre una lista de enteros separados por un espacio o puede ser cualquier cosa? ¿Lo que tienes es en realidad un xml?

Comment: Hola Sevilla: Si, es un XML. Y hay tanto enteros separados por espacio como strings (claves, campos de tuplas, ecta.).  Algunos entre >< y otros pegados al =

Comment: Hola Fernando en principio, si tienes un xml válido, lo suyo es usar un parser XML (usar REGEXs para parsear XML/HTML suelen ser una mala idea), por ejemplo el mismo [xml.etree.elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) de la biblioteca estándar o lxml, BeautifulSoup... Sería bueno que agregaras a la pregunta un pequeño ejemplo similar la real  de tu XML que contemple los diferentes  casos que comentas y que salida esperarías obtener al final para ese ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por tu Ayuda Sevilla. He añadido un poco más de explicación.

Comment: Fernando, he creado una respuesta usando Elemtree de la stdlib en vez de regex para obtener texto y atributos de todas las etiquetas del documento que los tengan. El uso de regex como comentaba no es apropiado por lo general para estas parsear un XML. No se exactamente como quieres usar los datos obtenidos, pero si te sirve de ayuda y surgen dudas comenta.

Comment: @FJSevilla: Infinitas Gracias. Tu respuesta es extraordinariamente educativa. Era lo que andaba buscando...  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar expresiones regulares para parsear archivos XML/HTML por norma general no es buena idea.  Las expresiones regulares no son la herramienta adecuada ni son suficientes para manejar la complejidad estructural de estos archivos, empezando por el manejo adecuado del anidamiento.

Lo apropiado en estos casos es usar un parser específico, en Python podemos usar el propio módulo [xml.etree.elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) de la biblioteca estándar o varias bibliotecas externas como [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) (más eficiente) o el mismo [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

Puedes obtener el dato asociado a cada etiqueta así como sus atributos de tenerlos (lo que va después del `=`) simplemente iterando sobre cada nodo del árbol. Por ejemplo:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree



doc = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mensaje date="01/10/2018">
    <Remitente>
        <Nombre type="org">Python</Nombre>
        <Mail>foo@mail.com</Mail>
    </Remitente>
</Mensaje>
"""


data = []

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(doc)
for node in tree.iter():
    tag = {"nombre": node.tag, "atributos": None, "valor": None}
    empty = True
    if node.attrib:
        tag["atributos"] = node.attrib
        empty = False
    if node.text.strip():
        tag["valor"] = node.text
        empty = False
    if not empty:
        data.append(tag)
```

Lo cual nos genera una lista de diccionarios con solo aquellas etiquetas que tienen texto o al menos un atributo:

> ```
> >>> data
> [{'nombre': 'Mensaje', 'atributos': {'date': '01/10/2018'}, 'valor': None},
>  {'nombre': 'Nombre', 'atributos': {'type': 'org'}, 'valor': 'Python'},
>  {'nombre': 'Mail', 'atributos': None, 'valor': 'foo@mail.com'}]
> ```

```
for tag in data:
    print(f"TAG: {tag['nombre']}")
    atributos = tag.get("atributos")
    dato = tag.get("valor")
    if atributos is not None:
        print("  ATRIBUTOS:")
        for atributo, valor in atributos.items():
            print(f"    {atributo} -> {valor}")

    if dato is not None:
        print(f"  DATO: {dato}")

    print()
```

> ```
> TAG: Mensaje
>   ATRIBUTOS:
>     date -> 01/10/2018
>
> TAG: Nombre
>   ATRIBUTOS:
>     type -> org
>   DATO: Python
>
> TAG: Mail
>   DATO: foo@mail.com
> ```

Puedes buscar si lo deseas a lo largo de todos los niveles del árbol una etiqueta determinada:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree


doc = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bandeja>
    <Mensaje date="01/10/2018">
        <Remitente>
            <Nombre type="pers_verf">Pedro</Nombre>
            <Mail>pedro@mail.com</Mail>
        </Remitente>
    </Mensaje>

    <Mensaje date="01/10/2018">
        <Remitente>
            <Nombre type="pers_unverf">Laura</Nombre>
            <Mail>laura@mail.com</Mail>
        </Remitente>
    </Mensaje>

    <Mensaje date="01/10/2018">
        <Remitente>
            <Nombre type="pers_verf">María</Nombre>
            <Mail>maria@mail.com</Mail>
        </Remitente>
    </Mensaje>
</Bandeja>
"""


data = []

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(doc)
for node in tree.iter("Nombre"):
    tag = {"nombre": node.tag, "atributos": None, "valor": None}
    empty = True
    if node.attrib:
        tag["atributos"] = node.attrib
        empty = False
    if node.text.strip():
        tag["valor"] = node.text
        empty = False
    if not empty:
        data.append(tag)



for tag in data:
    print(f"TAG: {tag['nombre']}")
    atributos = tag.get("atributos")
    dato = tag.get("valor")
    if atributos is not None:
        print("  ATRIBUTOS:")
        for atributo, valor in atributos.items():
            print(f"    {atributo} -> {valor}")

    if dato is not None:
        print(f"  DATO: {dato}")

    print()
```

> ```
> TAG: Nombre
>   ATRIBUTOS:
>     type -> pers_verf
>   DATO: Pedro
>
> TAG: Nombre
>   ATRIBUTOS:
>     type -> pers_unverf
>   DATO: Laura
>
> TAG: Nombre
>   ATRIBUTOS:
>     type -> pers_verf
>   DATO: María
> ```

Si solo se desea buscar los nodos con esa etiqueta que sean hijos de un determinado nodo padre se puede usar [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.findall). Como se puede ver usar un parser nos facilita la tarea enormemente.

> Para cargar el XML desde un archivo usar [`ElementTree.parse()`](http://tree%20=%20ElementTree.fromstring(doc)) en vez de `ElementTree.fromstring()`.